# How to send a cookie to authenticate with Crawlee (Apify)

Tags: apify, crawlee

From the documentation I can read only a function for saving

optionalpersistCookiesPerSession
persistCookiesPerSession?: boolean
Inherited from HttpCrawlerOptions.persistCookiesPerSession

Automatically saves cookies to Session. Works only if Session Pool is used.

It parses cookie from response “set-cookie” header saves or updates cookies for session and once the session is used for next request. It passes the “Cookie” header to the request with the session cookies.

But I just want to send the cookies stored in json file already.

searching for examples, I can't find any proper

Comment: It might be that the format for the JSON doesn't match the header format and you might have to manually parse it yourself, such as read the JSON file and then go through it exporting to the cookies each element?  Update - Drats .. I did a few searches to see if the AI knew of something else, but they ended up coming up with my same idea it seems.  This might be the solution I am afraid.

Comment: @easleyfixed thx very much for the response I found that in fact it works in json format when you send it as pre preNavigationHooks

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and here is the answer:

```js
import cookies from './cookies.json' assert { type: "json" }

...

const crawler = new PlaywrightCrawler({
    preNavigationHooks: [
        async (crawlingContext, gotoOptions) => {
            crawlingContext.page.context().addCookies(cookies)
        },
    ],
```

You can use this extension to gather the cookies first: [EditThisCookie](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg)

Hope that helps.